# How to set time in AM / PM

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am setting the base time below

```
      const baseTime = "9:00:00 AM"
      const convertedTime = new Date();

     const hour = baseTime.substring(0, baseTime.indexOf(':'));
      const minuite = baseTime.split(':')[1];
      convertedTime.setHours(parseInt(hour))
      convertedTime.setMinutes(parseInt(minuite))
```

How can I also set either the **AM** or **PM** value, because it always display **PM** even when the baseTime is **AM**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the AM or PM value of a Date object in JavaScript, you can use the setUTCHours method and pass in the desired hour, minute, and second values, as well as a value of 0 or 12 to indicate AM or PM.

If you want to set it to 9 PM, you can try out the following:

```
const baseTime = "9:00:00 PM";
const convertedTime = new Date();
const hour = baseTime.substring(0, baseTime.indexOf(':'));
const minute = baseTime.split(':')[1];
convertedTime.setUTCHours(parseInt(hour) + 12, parseInt(minute), 0, 0);
```

Do upvote if you find this answer useful :)